# JAVA Linked List How to loop through with a for loop?

Tags: java, linked-list

Hello I am trying to create a for loop that loops through the linked list. For each piece of data it will list it out individually. I am trying to learn linked list here, so no Array suggestions please. Anyone know how to do this?

Example Output:

1. Flight 187
2. Flight 501

---

CODE I HAVE SO FAR BELOW:

```
public static LinkedList<String> Flights = new LinkedList<String>();

public flightinfo(){
String[] flightNum = {"187", "501"};
        for (String x : flightNum)
        Flights.add(x);

                for (???)


}
```

Comment: Why are you iterating over the linked list? I'm confused by what you are trying to do. Right now, you have a LinkedList and an array of Strings, and you are iterating over that array of Strings to add them to a LinkedList. I don't understand what your end goal is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use the enhanced for-loop, the same way you'd do it with an array:

```
for(String flight : flights) {
   // do what you like with it
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If I understand you correctly, you have to get a reference to the List's iterator and use that to cycle through the data:

```
ListIterator iterator = Flights.iterator(); 
while (iterator.hasNext()){
  System.out.print(iterator.next()+" ");  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(String y : Flights) {
//...
}
```

The same way as arrays, since it inherits from `Iterable<T>`

As pointed out by @Cold Hawaiian this only works for Java >= 5.0

If pre 5.0 use:

```
ListIterator<String> iter = Flights.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
  String next = iter.next();
  // use next
}
```

Comment: This worked I copied the first for loop which was my mistake as it didn't teach me anything. Now I get it though!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use a ListIterator (see Java API for more information).

Answer (score 0):

If you have distinct values in the linked list , this would work :

```
for(Iterator<String> i = Flights.listIterator(); i.hasNext();){
    String temp = i.next();
    System.out.println(Flights.indexOf(temp)+1+". Flight "+temp );
}
```

If you do not have distinct values in the linked list, this would work :

```
int i=0;
for(Iterator<String> iter = Flights.listIterator(); iter.hasNext();i++){
    String temp = iter.next();
    System.out.println(i+1+". Flight "+temp );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With ***Java8*** Collection classes that implement Iterable have  a ***forEach()*** method. With ***forEach()*** and lambda expressions you can easily iterate over LinkedList

```
flights.forEach(flight -> System.out.println(flight));
```

Answer (score -3):

```
while(!flights.isEmptry) {
  System.out.println(flights.removeFirst());
}
```